# How can I tell if this matrix is a Binary Search Tree or Binary Tree.

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I’m trying to answer the following questions but I’m not really sure if matrix is a Binary Search Tree or Binary Tree. Is there any way to tell?

Find the least common ancestor between two nodes on a binary search tree. The least common ancestor is the farthest node from the root that is an ancestor of both nodes. For example, the root is a common ancestor of all nodes on the tree, but if both nodes are descendents of the root's left child, then that left child might be the lowest common ancestor. You can assume that both nodes are in the tree, and the tree itself adheres to all BST properties. The function definition should look like question4(T, r, n1, n2), where T is the tree represented as a matrix, where the index of the list is equal to the integer stored in that node and a 1 represents a child node, r is a non-negative integer representing the root, and n1 and n2 are non-negative integers representing the two nodes in no particular order. For example, one test case might be

```
question4([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],
3,
1,
4)
```

Comment: Doesn't the question already imply that it is a search tree& *(...) the tree itself adheres to all BST properties.*

Comment: yes thanks for replying. but I don't trust the question I want to know if it really is a BST

Comment: If I understand this representation correctly, then `2` is not connected to any other node (assuming zero-based indexing). Hence, it is no tree at all. Apart from that, the linking is apparently implicit. I.e., you need to maintain BST properties yourself. You could check if building a BST from the matrix is possible.

Comment: (I interpret the matrix thus: (3, ((0, 1), 4) - please give an example how to interpret the matrix. The row number corresponds to _the value stored_?!)

Comment: thanks @NicoSchertler, I don't get it where did you get 2 from?

Comment: From the third entry in the list (index 2)? All entries in row 2 are zero and all entries in column 2 are zero.

Comment: thanks @NicoSchertler but how do I maintain the BST properties myself? It would be nice if  someone could just draw the matrix as a tree so that I can understand it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think, the matrix represents the following graph:

[image: Graph]

The matrix should read as follows:

```
0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0
```

Row `0` represents node `0`. It has a `1` at index `1`, i.e. node `1` is a child of node `0`. The same method should apply to the other rows. E.g. node `0` and node `4` are children of node `3`.

To check if the graph is a tree, do the following: Every node in a tree (except the root) has exactly one parent. Hence, you need to make sure that all columns in the matrix have exactly one `1` entry (except for the root column, which should have no `1` entries).

To check if the tree is a binary tree, you need to check if a node has at most two children. You can do this by checking if every row has at most two `1` entries.

To check if a binary tree is a binary search tree, you have to check if there is at most one child in every subtree. I.e. in row `i`, there must be at most one `1` entry among entries `[0 .. i-1]` and at most one `1` entry among entries `[i+1 .. n-1]`. As greybeard pointed out, this condition is not sufficient because it does not regard higher-level ancestors. To check this, you need to construct the tree and traverse from root to leaves, checking if nodes fall in the allowed interval.

Comment: Hi @NicoSchertler thanks for the great and detailed explanation. I will accept the answer but I have one more questions. It looks like without the 2 the tree becomes a binary search tree am I right?

Comment: (Oops - one `not` duplicated instead of moved - next try: Given a node _p_ and its child _c_, every descendant of _p_ that is to the same side of _p_ as _c_ must be a descendant of _c_.)